# Difficulties with constructing this JavaScript regex

Tags: javascript, regex, lookbehind

I would like to construct a regular expression that matches any letter (including accented and Greek), number, hyphens and spaces with a total allowed characters length between 3 and 50.

This is what I made:

```
[- a-zA-Z0-9çæœáééíóúžàèìòùäëïöüÿâêîôûãñõåøαβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψωÇÆŒÁÉÍÓÚŽÀÈÌÒÙÄËÏÖÜŸÂÊÎÔÛÃÑÕÅØΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ]{3,50}
```

Now I wan't to adjust the expression so that it can't start with a hyphen or space. It will be used to validate a username.

I thought about using a negative lookbehind but these are the limitations:

- JavaScript doesn't support a lookbehind.
- The [alternatives](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript) for a lookbehind aren't really applicable since they all depend on other JavaScript functions and I am bound to using the match function.

I hope there are any regular expression heroes here since it doesn't look simple.

Comment: Just a tip: Check which unicode ranges the greek (and other letters) are in. You could than replace the long character list by `\uxxxx-\uyyyy`.

Comment: Nice tip. Gonna check that out!

Comment: This isn't a solution, but since nobody has said it yet, I want to make sure that you aren't solely using javascript to validate the user input.  You should definitely have some backend code that replicates the frontend validation.

Comment: That was the plan. Thanks for the reminder. Actually there will be three types of validation depending on the browser: JavaScript validation or HTML5 browser validation and PHP validation.

Comment: @Felix Kling - Your tip is worth gold. Imagine typing all those characters manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replaced your long character class with `a-z` for readability:

```
[a-z][- a-z]{2,49}
```

You could also match with your current regex and then make sure that the string does not match `^[ -]` in another match.

Comment: Seems to work but there's no option to prevent the whole a-z part from being duplicated? Since it's so long it would make it a lot more difficult to maintain.

Comment: you can use new RegExp(regex) if you want to convert a string to regular expression. This will allow you to set up your pattern in a string and manipulate/duplicate however you want.